# Train own classifier IBM Watson Visual Recognition Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, watson, visual-recognition

I already followed the steps from installing the SDK and configuring the service credentials. The problem is I cant train my own classifier. I'm getting this error: `No overload for method 'TrainClassifier' takes 5 arguments`.

```
void Start()
{
    string m_positiveExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/testData/cpu_positive_examples.zip";
    string m_negativeExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/testData/negative_examples.zip";
    if(!m_VisualRecognition.TrainClassifier("components", "cpu", m_positiveExamplesPath, m_negativeExamplesPath, OnTrainClassifier))
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Train classifier failed!");
}

private void OnTrainClassifier(GetClassifiersPerClassifierVerbose classifier)
{

    if(classifier != null)
    {
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Classifier is training! " + classifier);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Failed to train classifier!");
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk)'s the link of the SDK in GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied that code from the [example page](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk) but looks like that everything on that page is outdated. It needs to be updated by IBM.

The [`VisualRecognition`](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/1da86591d222c809c00910a9b19dcfaf4bfff8b2/Scripts/Services/VisualRecognition/VisualRecognition.cs) class has 2 overloads of `TrainClassifier`:

```
public bool TrainClassifier(OnTrainClassifier callback, string classifierName, Dictionary<string, string> positiveExamples, string negativeExamplesPath = default(string), string mimeType = "application/zip", string customData = default(string))
```

and

```
public bool TrainClassifier(OnTrainClassifier callback, string classifierName, Dictionary<string, byte[]> positiveExamplesData, byte[] negativeExamplesData = null, string mimeType = "application/zip", string customData = default(string))
```

You have the SDK right in front of you. Next time you get an error like this, select the function, right click **Go To Definition**. It will show you the overload of the function then you will be able to pass the right parameter inside it.

[image]

Your code should be something like this:

```
private VisualRecognition m_VisualRecognition = new VisualRecognition();

void Start()
{
    string m_positiveExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/testData/cpu_positive_examples.zip";
    string m_negativeExamplesPath = Application.dataPath + "/testData/negative_examples.zip";

    Dictionary<string, string> positiveExamples = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    positiveExamples.Add("giraffe", m_positiveExamplesPath);

    if (!m_VisualRecognition.TrainClassifier(OnTrainClassifier, "unity-test-classifier-example", positiveExamples, m_negativeExamplesPath))
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Train classifier failed!");
}

private void OnTrainClassifier(GetClassifiersPerClassifierVerbose classifier, string data)
{

    if (classifier != null)
    {
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Classifier is training! " + classifier);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Failed to train classifier!");
    }
}
```

If you need any other example, **don't** get it from the [example page](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk). Get it from the *Example folder* that comes with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks man, I learned something today. I tried to run the code but I didn`t got any response from the console. Do you have any idea why? I hope I`m not asking too much. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get a response. My answer is to fix your `No overload for method 'TrainClassifier' takes 5 arguments` error. Please create a new question for other problems. I will take a look at them. Don't forget to accept this if your error is gone.